# VS2012 - Build - Transform text templates

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, t4

We have a relatively large solution file (25 projects). If I build any one of these projects, the final build step is "Transforming templates for all project items". Does anyone know where the setting is to toggle this functionality in visual studio 2012.

I thought it was my 'power commands' plugin which was doing this, but I've turned it off but doing so hasn't stopped the functionality.

It causes all the builds to hang for 5 - 6 seconds at the end, and for something that isn't really needed for each and every build its getting a bit annoying.

[image]

--Edit

I got frustrated and removed a bunch of add-ins from my VS but no luck.

These were:

- VS Power Commands
- VS productivity tools
- Tangible T4 Editor (free)

Strange thing is, in one branch it doesn't do it and in others it does, even after a full merge. I tried deleting the .suo file but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot off ways this can be done but did you look at [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee847423.aspx)

I've a very large project and now work with an custom solution to handle the generation I use unit test and [T4Host](https://github.com/smangelschots/T4Host)